# JSF 2 view resolver for spring 3

Tags: spring-mvc, jsf-2

I have working jsf 2 (primefaces) + spring 3 multi module project.

The spring beans are grouped by domain logic in different reusable modules.
How ever all my xhtml pages and resources are placed in the war module.

Now i need to move some pages and resources to one of my modules, because it must not be deployed in production.

I saw that there is a `viewResolver` beans in spring which can map logical names to pages and resources in another module and i can use this logical name to define it in my war module without knowing or have a reference to the resource from the other module.

It is not very clear to me, how to accomplish this? Can you point me to example or blog or any advice?

Comment: Spring is an umbrella name for many spring solutions it may be IOC container, Spring WebFlow, Spring MVC etc. Please be more specific on what parts of spring you are using with JSF 2.

Answer (score 3):

In JSF you can achieve that by extending facelets [DefaultResourceResolver](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/faces/facelets/impl/DefaultResourceResolver.java.html)

```
public class PackegedResourceResolver extends DefaultResourceResolver {

    @Override
    public URL resolveUrl(String resource) {
        URL resourceUrl = super.resolveUrl(resource);

        if (resourceUrl == null) {
            resourceUrl = PackegedResourceResolver.class.getResource("/META-INF/pages/" + resource);
        }

        return resourceUrl;
    }

}
```

Register it in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.RESOURCE_RESOLVER</param-name>
    <param-value>com.example.facelets.PackegedResourceResolver</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The `PackegedResourceResolver` will use the default resource resolver and if nothing is found will look under `/WEB-INF/pages` of each jar in your classpath.
It means you can place your `.xhtml` page under `/META-INF/pages` inside any jars (modules) that is available in the classpath.

With slight modification this approach can also be used to hide the `.xhtml` sources under /WEB-INF/ dir of your war.

Comment: Note that this is Facelets 1.x specific and OP is using JSF 2.x. Also note that resources in `/META-INF/resources` of any arbitrary JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` are then automagically scanned without the need for a custom resolver.

Comment: I don't agree, i put my xhtml component in the WAR webapp/resources directory and it worked. When i put it in the JAR META-INF/resources it does not worked.
I had to write tag library xml where i describe the component.
Resources like images, css, js work, but xhtml files don't work just like that.